# Two Step Auth with Azure B2C between frontEnd React and SpringBoot backend

Tags: reactjs, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-ad-b2c

I have a React application and a SpringBoot backend that I want to secure with Azure B2C.

I Have successfully created an auth Flow in the frontend with React and B2C and I reach the Access Token. Now In my idea I should pass the access token to SpringBoot, that should call B2C to validate my identity by the access token and get the userInfo and role. But in All Microsoft's Documentation I could't find any example for the validation. All the examples for b2C involve the authentication on a web-server-hosted page, with login in web-server. Anyone that can help my with a link to some documentation or example? 
Thank You very much

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this?

Comment: Following is the link which do the exact thing here 
https://ordina-jworks.github.io/security/2020/08/18/Securing-Applications-Azure-AD.html

But its not working for me. I am getting following error

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed